# Cognito Forms - Customise Receipt Number

Tags: cognito-forms

I need to have a customized receipt number and not use the auto generated F - number.
How do I do that?
I want to change it from F6E62T1 to KB00001 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Make a calculation field named ReceiptNumber, the calculation would be

```
="KB" + Entry.Number.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0')
```

Please be aware that this will only show a number **AFTER** the entry has been submitted